# Rename multiple mp3 files using track number from old name

Tags: regex, sed, find, rename, mv

I wanted to organize my mp3 files and rename them using the pattern `track##.mp3` where `##` is track number.

I need a regular expression that selects the track number, which is the first two characters in the old name.

Example:

```
01 - Album Artist - track name.mp3
```

and output should be

```
track01.mp3
```

How do I do this? I am trying some find with sed command or just plane rename, but I am not successful. Regular expression is too complicated for me.

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: or use a tool.. https://www.advancedrenamer.com/   or some other one, this one showed up as second from goolge

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the Perl-style `rename`, you can use

```
for fname in *.mp3; do mv "$fname" "track${fname:0:2}.mp3"; done
```

This uses `mv` and parameter expansion to extract the first two characters.